# What does this syntax mean in a for loop? : return [-x for x in lst]

Tags: python

I encountered a problem online where I had to write a function that takes a list of numbers and I have to return its additive inverse. This was one of the answers but I don't understand how does that exactly work?:

```
def invert(lst):
    return [-x for x in lst]
```

Comment: That's a *list comprehension* - look it up, it's a very useful Python technique.

Comment: https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/

Comment: Make this a running example that prints the return value. Is it clear?

Comment: [What does "list comprehension" and similar mean? How does it work and how can I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34835951/11082165)

Answer (score -1):

```py
def invert(lst):
    return [-x for x in lst]
```

=

```py
def invert(lst):
   return_list = []
   for x in lst:
      return_list.append(-x)
   return return_list
```

Comment: There is 0 need to answer questions like this - perfect duplicates exist.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @luk2302 but sometimes people like me really want to help people(yes nice people on stackoverflow they are here)

Comment: If you don't have time to enter this,just do comment